# IF statement to apply different formula

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am looking to create a field that tells me how many points a player is earning by scoring or assisting goals in FPL. Since there are different points per goal depending on position (GK, Defender, Midfield, Forward), but assists grant the same amount of points (3), I need the code to identify the position of the player and multiply it depending on the points he gets for each position.

Code below:

```py
multi_goal = if df['element_type'] == 'FWD': 4
            elif df['element_type'] == 'MID': 5
            elif df['element_type'] == 'DEF': 6
            else df['element_type'] == 'GK': 6

goals_int = df['goal_part'] = (df['goals_scored']*multigoal) + (df['assists']*3)
```

The 'multigoal' object gives this error:

```
multi_goal = if df['element_type'] == 'FWD': 4
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: As the error states, the syntax is not correct for python.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simpler synthaxe like :

```
if df['element_type'] == 'FWD':
    multi_goal = 4
elif df['element_type'] == 'MID':
    multi_goal = 5
...
```

Or you can implement a switch statement, https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, I would use dictionary and `map`:

```
dmap = {'FWD': 4,
       'MID':5,
       'DEF':6,
       'GK':6}

df = pd.DataFrame({'Position':['FWD','FWD','MID','DEF','GK'],
                   'goals_scored':[1,2,1,3,0],
                   'assists':[0,3,1,1,2]})

 df['goal_part'] = df['goals_scored']*df['Position'].map(dmap) + df['assists']*3
```

Output:

```
  Position  goals_scored  assists  goal_part
0      FWD             1        0          4
1      FWD             2        3         17
2      MID             1        1          8
3      DEF             3        1         21
4       GK             0        2          6
```